# I'm really stumped on this MySQL problem

Tags: mysql

I noticed that searches for a particular word wasn't working on our user search, I've narrowed the problem down to this small example.

If you create a test table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `names` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert  into `names`(`id`,`name`) values (1,'Joseph');
insert  into `names`(`id`,`name`) values (2,'Dick');
insert  into `names`(`id`,`name`) values (3,'Rather');
insert  into `names`(`id`,`name`) values (4,'Steven');
insert  into `names`(`id`,`name`) values (5,'Anna');
```

And perform this search:

```
SELECT * FROM `names` WHERE MATCH(NAME) AGAINST ('+rather* ' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

You will see that there are no results.
However substituting 'rather' for any of the other names in the table works fine...
What's wrong with 'Rather'???

It's mysql version 5.5.8.

Any help greatly appreciated... I really have no idea on this one!!

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rather` is a MySQL [stopword](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/fulltext-stopwords.html). You cannot full text search for it by default.

To work around that, you can disable stopwords by setting the [ft_stopword_file](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_ft_stopword_file) system variable to the empty string.

Comment: But "Rather" is part of my name! boo hoo :( I wonder what other search results I'm missing out on on the web... Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

'Rather' is the stopword for full text search in BOOLEAN mode for MySql

for more details you can see the following links 
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html

Answer (score 0):

apparently you didnt create fulltext index

check this:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-search.html

Comment: Even after altering the table as such, the same problem happens: ALTER TABLE `names` ADD FULLTEXT `NewIndex1` (`name`);